# Missing 64-bit support. iOS apps submitted to the App Store must include 64-bit support

Tags: swift, xcode, arm64

full log is :

```
    ERROR ITMS-90086: "Missing 64-bit support. iOS apps submitted to the App Store must include 64-bit support and be built with the iOS 8 SDK or later. We recommend using the default "Standard Architectures" build setting for "Architectures" in Xcode, to build a single binary with both 32-bit and 64-bit support."
ERROR ITMS-90086: "Missing 64-bit support. iOS apps submitted to the App Store must include 64-bit support and be built with the iOS 8 SDK or later. We recommend using the default "Standard Architectures" build setting for "Architectures" in Xcode, to build a single binary with both 32-bit and 64-bit support."
```

I have set build active architecture to no

my architectures are :

```
architectures : armv7
valid architectures : armv6, armv7, armv7s, arm64
```

no phone connected to Xcode

Xcode version 8.3

I have cheek other threads here none of them helped me.so this might be duplicate question but it is different

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that AppStore submissions after April require Xcode 9 and iOS11.

> Starting April 2018, all new iOS apps submitted to the App Store must
>   be built with the iOS 11 SDK. All new apps for iPhone, including
>   universal apps, must support the Super Retina display of iPhone X.

Try to write in the voice of Build Settings Architecture `$(ARCHS_STANDARD)` to be sure to pick up all the architectures, but I still think it will fail.

Comment: thanks Andrea. I did update my Xcode.now I went through the same. this time was successful but appStore icon missing warning.i did push Done button. so what now?? how can I find my app?? I cheek my iTunes connect still waiting for submission

Comment: If uploading the ipa showed you an error it probably blocked the whole process and no build will be present on iTunesConnect. If it is a warning go to iTunesConnect site login, select your app and check the activity tab. If it is there and available you can pick your build in the AppStore -> App iOS tab. Please be aware that the whole uploading process is pretty well documented by Apple, take some time to read the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Update your Xcode through the App Store, Xcode 9.x is the latest version. Then update your code to the new version of Swift and submit again. Hope this helps! - Colin